# Entity Framework - Navigation Property External Source

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class (Employee) within my DBContext and I want to join that with another class (Office) via a navigation property.  The Office class is something that comes from an external source.  Is this something that can be easily done?

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string OfficeCode { get; set; }

    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
}

public class Office
{
    public string OfficeCode { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public MyContext() : base("name=constring")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The Office can be gathered with:

```
Office GetOfficeByOcd(string ocd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this...
Since Office is not really part of your db model you can't have "foreign key" property like OfficeCode.
Nothing prevents you from adding the GetOfficeByOcd method on the Employee class though.

That said,since the GetOfficeByOcd method doesn't really depend on the Employee it's probably better to move it to a more suitable place (Like the Office class or an OfficeService)

Comment: That's too bad.  Thank you for the clarification.